# I can't download El Capitan from App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I think the title is pretty selfdescribing, but ok :)

I go to App Store, I click on download button on OS X El Capitan (it is listed under Utilities), and nothing happens and the El Capitan is not downloaded, nor does it change the status to "Downloading". I don't think it is downloading. I also tried to log in as root to the mac and now the App Store won't work - it keeps spinning the spinner sign and nothing happens, I can't even type the letters "El Capitan" in the search box. Anyone has any other link, URL for downloading of El Capitan, other than the one on App Store? Losing my faith in Apple slowly......
I am on Macbook 7.1 (Mid-2010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the computer, and tried again, solved the problem.