# El Capitan download problems

Tags: macos

I am trying to update a mac mini from OS 10 10 5 up to ElCap

App store tells me the app has Downloaded but nothing happens

I have looked at a few posts on this forum so have looked in the Apps folder but there is no El Cap installer there.

Any ideas how I can force another download, or find the installer on my machine(assuming it has actually downloaded)

Any ideas

Comment: Don't know whether it's related but there seem to be certification problems at the OSX App Store.  http://www.macrumors.com/2016/03/03/older-os-x-installers-broken-by-certificate/

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart your computer and try repeat last actions.

It was helpful at similar [discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/229700/119284).